# How big is the deja-dup download?

Tags: ssh, backup, deja-dup

I have successfully backed up my laptop data using `deja-dup`. I used a dedicated backup server, which I connected to using `ssh` over my home LAN. The size of the backup on the server disk is 250 GB.

Afterwards, I am trying to create an incremental backup from the same laptop, this time from my workplace. The destination machine is the very same server, but this time, of course, I had to change the address.

I opened a port for SSH and installed noip on the server.

After starting the backup, deja-dup is forever in the "Preparing" stage. `iftop` tells me that I am *downloading* data from the backup server at about 300 KiB/s.

I guess deja-dup needs to keep track of what is on the server already: *is this correct?*

A related question is: *given a backup size of (for example) 259 GB, how much data will deja-dup download before starting the backup?*

Comment: If you are really going to use this on a server it might be easier to use duplicity rather than deja dup. It does the same thing, but it gives a lot more insight into what is really happening

Answer (score 2):

I actually found an answer.

During the "Preparing" phase, `deja-dup` downloads the "signature" file. Since my "signature" file is ~3.0 GB, it will take ~2.5 h to complete the stage, given the current line speed.